# How to get rid of loading source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm on every shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have two projects one use ruby 2.2.1 and other one use 2.2.3
When I start server of first one it works while when I do this for 2.2.3 it gives an error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3
```

Then I do `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and `rvm use ruby-2.2.3`

How I get rid of this?
My `.bashrc` last line is

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Comment: If you do `rvm use ruby-2.2.3` it works?

Comment: Presumably you're trying to get rid of the source line, so ensure it's included in your `.bash_profile` file. Then you just call on `rvm` to manage which version of ruby should be used

Comment: I prefer to have a `.rvmrc` file within each root path of my projects. Within each file of a project there is a line like yours: `rvm use ruby-2.2.1` or `rvm use ruby-2.2.3`. So the right ruby interpreter is used if I enter a project directory. This assumes, that you have a working rvm installed and it's sourced in your .bash_profile or a similar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use automatic ruby switching by having one of these files: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects.
I personally prefer a `.ruby-version` file.